# SwiftUI CoreData not saving / not detecting changes

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have an entity called Cart, but it seems I can't get it to save a new data from my viewmodel.

Persistence.swift

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newCart = Cart(context: viewContext)
            newCart.menuName = "name"
            newCart.menuImg = "img"
            newCart.menuCode = "code"
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Project")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
    
    func save() {
        let context = container.viewContext

        if context.hasChanges {
            print("Found Changes")
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print("ERROR")
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        } else {
            print("NO Changes")
        }
    }
}
```

MenuViewModel.swift

```
class MenuViewModel.swift: ObservableObject, MenuDetailService {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    func addToCart() {
        let newCart = Cart(context: managedObjectContext)
        newCart.menuCode = menuCode
        newCart.menuName = menuName
        newCart.menuImg = menuImg
        PersistenceController.shared.save()
    }
}
```

ProjectApp.swift

```
@main
struct ProjectApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }.onChange(of: scenePhase) { _ in
            persistenceController.save()
        }
    }
}
```

The persistence controller func save() always print no changes, seems like I use different context? and I don't know how to use the context in the persistence controller to save the new data. How do I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry what is transient? I wanted it to be saved such as SQLlite, I'm following from this tutorial: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/introduction-to-using-core-data-with-swiftui

Comment: Strangely even though in the tutorial the save function is defined like in your example, it uses PersistenceController.shared.saveContext() instead. Might be an error in the tutorial, or you might try that as well?

Comment: Where/how do you call addToCart?

Comment: On further inspection, you can’t use @Environment in your view model class, it’s only accessible from a type that comforts to `View`. So use dependency injection or access the managed context via the persistence controller.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you for your answer, yes the thing is I don't know hot to access the managed context via the persistence controller, tried a lot of things but returns error. turns out it's like lorem ipsum's answer below. thx mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Remove the `.swift` 
class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject, MenuDetailService {
    //@Environment does not work well outside of a struct :View . Updates are unreliable
    var managedObjectContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    // You need to pass the variables somehow to the new object when you call the method from the `View`
    func addToCart(menuCode: String, menuName: String, menuImg: UIImage) {
        let newCart = Cart(context: managedObjectContext)
        newCart.menuCode = menuCode
        newCart.menuName = menuName
        newCart.menuImg = menuImg
        PersistenceController.shared.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! works like a charm. such simple solution, didn't really know how to use the viewContext, you just saved my day